# Unable to add users to BigQuery project

Tags: google-bigquery

I am trying to add users to my BigQuery project using the admin console. When I add the users, they receive the following error during signup

> Error: you have no more apps available to accept this invitation.

What other steps am I missing to add an user?

Thanks.

Comment: We'll need more information! Project id?

Answer (score 0):

1. Go to URL@ https://console.developers.google.com/project

   1. Click on your project
   2. click on "permissions" menu link item, which is placed in left hand side
   3. Click on "ADD MEMBER" Button - and then you can add the email accounts with the permission type like "ADMIN" "VIEW" and "EDIT"
      types.

Hope this helps :)